# Is /proc/cpuinfo locale dependent?

Tags: language-support, cpuinfo

I want to parse the `cpu MHz` field in `/proc/cpuinfo` to a float number.

In different locales, the `.` of `2599.998` can be `,`.

I changed my locale to be `pt_PT` and I see the output is still `2599.998` (with `.`), but I am looking for someone that can assure me that the output of `/proc/cpuinfo` does not depend on the current locale.

Comment: I tested with another locale (`tr_TR.UTF-8`) where comma is used as a decimal separator, but the contents of `/proc/cpuinfo` are still the same (with `.`). I assume this is so because the contents of this "file" are filled by the kernel which is NOT locale aware.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I tested it too, but is this written in official docs?

Comment: Yes, the output for the `cpu MHz` line of `/proc/cpuinfo` is not locale dependent. It is a kernel thing and nothing to do with Ubuntu. That being said, I upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to see decimal numbers using `,` I can suggest you a workaround, using this command line :

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | sed "s/\./,/g"
```

Explanation :

- `cat /proc/cpuinfo` would show you each current cpu informations
- `sed "s/\./,/g"` would replace each `.` with a `,` so your CPU frequency would be shown as you want (`2599,998`); also, we use `\` because the `.` is a special character

You can add a `grep` command to get only what you want (frequency for example) :

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | sed "s/\./,/g" | grep MHz
```

or redirect results into a text file :

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | sed "s/\./,/g" > cpu.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, but my question is, is the `/proc/cpuinfo` will always return a `.`?

Comment: Although the answer of @damadam is not about what you are asking for, you can use the `sed` command to replace any (possible) `,` to `.` to have a consistent output. Still I am *not sure* whether the answer to your question is that "No, it is not locale dependent".

Comment: @baruchiro I tried to do the mot suitable answer to your question, better than just a "Yes/No" answer, by giving you a command that would display CPU informations using the comma decimal comma (which is the point in english form)